# Nginx unable to get SSL cert to work

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, letsencrypt, cert-manager

I'm trying to get a kubernetes cluster using the nginx ingress controller and cert manager to get an SSL cert from lets encrypt. Currently is appears the cert has been issued however I am unable to get it to load properly inside Chrome or via curl.

Below are some config files that show the current config and following that some describes.

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: cert-manager-prod
spec:
  selfSigned: {}
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: cert-manager-prod
spec:
  commonName: me@example.com <- This is not actually what I have just for example reasons
  secretName: letsencrypt-prod-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
```

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    # add an annotation indicating the issuer to use.
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    # needed to allow the front end to talk to the back end
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://portal.<domain>.com"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
    # needed for monitoring - maybe
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/port: "10254"
    #for nginx ingress controller
    ad.datadoghq.com/nginx-ingress-controller.check_names: '["nginx","nginx_ingress_controller"]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/nginx-ingress-controller.init_configs: '[{},{}]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/nginx-ingress-controller.instances: '[{"nginx_status_url": "http://%%host%%:18080/nginx_status"},{"prometheus_url": "http://%%host%%:10254/metrics"}]'
    ad.datadoghq.com/nginx-ingress-controller.logs: '[{"service": "controller", "source":"nginx-ingress-controller"}]'
  name: prod-ingress
  namespace: production
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.<domain>.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 8090
        path: /
  tls: # < placing a host in the TLS config will indicate a certificate should be created
  - hosts:
    - api.<domain>.com
    secretName: prod-ingress-cert # < cert-manager will store the created certificate in this secre
```

```
me@LAPTOP-LINUX:~/Projects/k8/tmp$ kubectl get certificates
NAME                READY   SECRET              AGE
prod-ingress-cert   False   prod-ingress-cert   30m
```

```
Name:         prod-ingress-cert
Namespace:    production
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-01-26T21:29:07Z
  Generation:          1
  Owner References:
    API Version:           extensions/v1beta1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Ingress
    Name:                  prod-ingress
    UID:                   adec15ea-4cde-4376-8e6a-306586e57119
  Resource Version:        2780
  Self Link:               /apis/cert-manager.io/v1alpha2/namespaces/production/certificates/prod-ingress-cert
  UID:                     c86bf4aa-8435-4da0-a822-1a0e9d1df38e
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    api.<domain>.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:      cert-manager.io
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-prod
  Secret Name:  prod-ingress-cert
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2020-01-26T21:29:07Z
    Message:               Waiting for CertificateRequest "prod-ingress-cert-1024021523" to complete
    Reason:                InProgress
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age   From          Message
  ----    ------        ----  ----          -------
  Normal  GeneratedKey  30m   cert-manager  Generated a new private key
  Normal  Requested     30m   cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "prod-ingress-cert-1024021523"
```

That's everything I can think of that might be of use in resolving this issue. I should note I have a similar setup running on development (well did till I took the cluster down today) that is/was working.

Answer (score 1):

Issue ended up being that I was creating a self signed cert because I was using the wrong issuer. I had an issue before with the dev.yaml file but never updated for this new ENV.